# Google calendars API error - tooManyCalendarsRequested

Tags: google-calendar-api

Getting this error, and for the life of me I can't find any documentation online for how many is too many. Anyone have an idea, or a way to find out?

Here's the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query

Comment: why not start removing some and see when you hit the magic number?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to set the maximum id, read the documentation:

> Maximal number of calendars for which FreeBusy information is to be provided. Optional.

I checked it worked well with 50 items.

```
req.setCalendarExpansionMax(50);
```

[Here's a link to the documentation.](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/calendar_v3.freebusy.html)

Comment: @Ninjarabbi If my answer can fix your case, please accepted my answer.

Answer (score -2):

The maximum calendars you can request is 20.
(i've made my own tests)

Comment: any source for this?

Comment: It's set to 20 if you don't set it yourself. See answer above to be able to set the limit yourself.